# lit() function to be parameterized in spark scala

Tags: apache-spark

I am using the `lit()` function in the `filter` transformation in my spark code as below

```
filter(to_date(df1("process_date"))>=lit("2019-03-21"))
```

This works well when the parameter to `lit()` is hard-coded as shown above.

I want to parameterize the value I have passed to the `lit()` function. Can anyone tell how this can be achieved and how the parameter needs to be passed in `spark-submit` for this please.

Comment: why is a lit needed? val df2 = df.filter($"b" === "foo") works fine

Comment: @thebluephantom.. good point, i forgot that.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Spark Submit Command

```
spark-submit --class SparkExample spark_example.jar "2019-03-21"
```

Inside Code

```
object SparkExample {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
     val date = args(0)
     val df = [...] // your code to create dataframe.
     df.filter(to_date(df1("process_date"))>=lit(date))
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks Srinivas, the above cde worked , thanks a lot

Comment: Please accept the solution if it helps.. :)